Qt c++ как использовать указатель на основное окно в дополнительном окне в нескольких функциях?
Этот вопрос возник, когда я пытался связать 2 окна, но это ладно, это работает, также мне надо было использовать слоты и сигналы, а запихать их в ту же функцию, которая открывает основное окно по нажатию кнопки, не вышло, выдало ошибку. Попытался объявить указатель в заговолочном файле, но так не принимает, говорит, что мб я имел в виду QMainWindow, а не MainWindow, который нужен мне, с QMainWindow возникают шибки уже в основной части кода, говорит что моя переменная не объявлена. Вот код:
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"
#include "QPushButton"
#include "QVBoxLayout"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "QTextCodec"
//#include "QWidget"
Form::Form(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    MainWindow *m2w = new MainWindow;
    connect(ui->baton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Form::OP);
    connect(this, &Form::txt1, m2w, &MainWindow::slot1);
    connect(this, &Form::txt2, m2w, &MainWindow::slot2);
    ui->baton->setEnabled(false);
}
/*Form::Form(MainWindow *m2w, QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent), m2w(m2w) {
}*/
void Form::OP()
{
    //MainWindow *m2w = new MainWindow;
    //MainWindow *m3w = m2w;
    m2w->show();
}
Form::~Form()
{
    delete ui;
}
void Form::on_knopka_clicked()
{
    emit txt1(ui->a1->text());
    emit txt2(ui->a2->text());
    ui->baton->setEnabled(true);
}

m2w - указатель на основное окно
В основной функции происходит коннект сигналов и слотов, ну и вызов функции OP, которая открывает основное окно. Пример заговолочного файла:
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>
#include <mainwindow.h>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTextCodec>
namespace Ui
{
class Form;
}
class Form : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    //MainWindow *m2w = new MainWindow;
    Form(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
~Form();
signals:
    void txt1(QString a);
    void txt2(QString a);
private slots:
    void OP();
    void on_knopka_clicked();
    //void on_a1_textchanged();
    //void on_a2_textchanged();
private:
    MainWindow *m2w = new MainWindow;
    Ui::Form *ui;
    QPushButton *knopka;
};
/*Form::Form(MainWindow *m2w, QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent), m2w(m2w) {
}*/
#endif  // FORM_H


Объявите переменную - член класса. MainWindow *m2w;

Где именно? Если объявить в заголовочном файле, то вылезает ошибка, если в функции OP, то возникает ошибка с 2 коннектами, если в основной функции, то возникает ошибка с функцией OP, ибо не знаю, как в неё передать этот указатель

В заголовочном файле, внутри класса. (:Предпочтительно, в секции private  или protected).

Объявил в заголовке: ругается, что переменная не обьявлена(эт в обычном файле .cpp), ругается и говорит, что я возможно имел в виу QMainWindow, а я не имел ее в виду(эт в заголовке ошибка .h)

говорит в заговолочном файле, что "MainWindow" does not name a type, did you mean 'QMainWindow'?

В заголовочном файле только объявление: MainWindow *m2w; . В .cpp  (в конструкторе) - только инициализация m2w = new MainWindow;.  Не надо совмещать объявление и инициализацию.

Попробовал. Те же ошибки выдает, что я описал чуть раньше

А что значит "MainWindow" does not name a type, did you mean 'QMainWindow'? Эта ошибка возникает не из-за того, что файл ссылается на основной класс из заголовочного файла? Тип, эт объявдение работает, если оно в обычном файле(.cpp), но именно в заголовке объявдение не принимает

MainWindow - я предполагаю, это класс,,  который вы определили в mainwindow.h. Возможно, вы не сделали include. (Хотя в примере я его вижу.) Возможно, создали циклическое включение include.

Ошибка была судя по всему в том, что у меня в mainwindow.h был include,я его убрал, также в main.cpp поменял include<MainWindow.h> на include,Form>. Помогло, терь все открывается и ошибки нет, правда она у меня терь в другом появляется, но данная тема решена. СПАСИБО огромное вам, Chorkov!
